# Dataflow JTDS SL Server Validation Query

Tags: java, sql-server, google-cloud-dataflow, jtds

I'm currently trying to connect to a SQL Server from a Dataflow job using the JDBCIO step of a pipeline. I am getting the following error:

```
2022-12-21T15:06:16.7965222Z SEVERE: 2022-12-21T15:04:31.071Z: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7966124Z    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7967191Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:895)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7968254Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:273)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7969451Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:644)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7970625Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7971833Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:652)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7973522Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:534)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7974830Z    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734)
    2022-12-21T15:06:16.7976091Z    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:1354)
```

I have found online that I need to be able to set a validation query on the data source, but I don't know how to do that from within the dataflow job. Below is the code I'm using to set up the connection - can I add a validation query? Is there another workaround?

```
PCollection<Row> Coll = pipeline
            .apply("Connect", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                    .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                            buildDataSourceConfig(options, URL))
                    .withQuery(query)
                    .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<TableRow>() {
                      // Convert ResultSet to PCollection
                      public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
                        String ipAddress = rs.getString("IP");
                        return trOf(ipAddress);
                      }
                    }))

private static DataSourceConfiguration buildDataSourceConfig(Options options, String url)
          throws Exception {
    
    return DataSourceConfiguration
            .create("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver", url)
            .withUsername(user)
            .withPassword(pass);
  }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server? jTDS hasn't had a release in nearly a decade and was incomplete even back then, lacking support for `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types amongst other things.

Comment: The JDBC driver throws a domain exception when trying to use NTLM authentication:

 java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

This happens if the pipeline is ran locally, or ran in the cloud in GCP. When using JTDS, though, I can connect running the pipeline locally, but not when running from the cloud because of the error above.

Answer (score 1):

You could create DataSource separately and pass it to DataSourceConfiguration constructor (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.html)

When creating DataSource, you should be able to set validation query:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setValidationQuery-java.lang.String-

Comment: That would work, but it looks like the DataSourcConfiguration constructor only takes a javax.sql.DataSource, which does not have the same properties as a org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

Comment: Yeah but BasicDataSource implements javax.sql.DataSource interface, so you should be able to pass it anyway?

Comment: Only other issue is that the data source needs to be serializable:

2022-12-29T14:59:07.0182500Z Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource must be Serializable
2022-12-29T14:59:07.0184040Z    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
2022-12-29T14:59:07.0185868Z    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$DataSourceConfiguration.create(JdbcIO.java:464)
2022-12-29T14:59:07.0188156Z    at edu.mayo.mcc.aide.confidentialDocuments.Confid...

Comment: Man... OK, use:
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClass("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

      dataSource.setJdbcUrl(<YOUR URL>);
      dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
      JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration config = JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(dataSource);

Comment: I think this brings us back to the original issue - ComboPooledDatasource doesn't seem to have a setValidationQuery function (or similar)

Comment: Damn. Tricky... Last try, use the actual JdsDataSource, it should be serializable : 

JtdsDataSource jt = new JtdsDataSource();
        jt.setServerName("localhost");
        jt.setPortNumber(1433);
        jt.setUseNTLMV2(true);
        jt.setDatabaseName("master");

Comment: Thanks for the help! This method worked using the ComboPooledDataSource's  setPreferredTestQuery to set the validation function